# Strategy BackTest profit difference between Heiken Ashi and Normal Candles

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Hi All I Just backtested a strategy in 15 min chart from 01-06-2022 to till date with Heiken Ashi and Regular candles and there is a huge difference in Profit

pic 1 Heiken Ashi:
[image]

Pic 2 - Regular Candles

[image]
Can Someone explain why there is difference ....if HA candles are profitable for my strategy can i go with the same for real time markets...does the strategy yield the same results as backtested with HA candles or will it yield different results in real market .....advise needed .... is HA candles for my strategy is better.... or regular candles is showing the exact real time market outputs ....pls advise

Answer (score 1):

Heiken Ashi  candle open values are different from actual open values. So the entry exit done at candle open will show incorrect values. Hence you will not get same returns in real time trading.

If you want to find real PL using Heiken Ashi candle, then you can use normal candle on chart. And calculate heiken ashi candle open close in code. Then feed the calculate open close to the different indicators to generate signals. But the buy and sell will get done using normal candle and so it will be accurate.

```
heikinashiclose=  (open+high+low+close)/4.0
heikinashiopene=  (open[1]+close[1])/2.0
```

Comment: what if i follow  Heiken Ashi candle, in Binance & tradingview together while the strategy is linked and is on ...... do i get the same values as in trading view backtest open & close values

Comment: is the same values open & close trades in HA candles in trading view apply also when the strategy is linked to binance and binance is also configured to HA candles

Comment: i am sorry, i dont have knowledge of binance, you can post that as new question tagging pine-script and binance etc